# Syntax error in trying to assign execution permissions for script in Python

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

So, I am learning to execute script files in Python and reading online I found a source that showed how one can run the script by using file name.

Here is the code:

```
# Assign execution permissions
chmod +x hello.py
# Run the script by using its filename
./hello.py
Hello World!
```

When I try to implement the same in my Jupyter notebook I get a syntax error.

```
  File "<ipython-input-14-a06e550a5f88>", line 2
    chmod +x hello.py
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Since I am just learning about this, I have no clue why this error shows up.

Comment: That's _not_ Python code. It's the instruction to make a Python script executable then execute it, from your shell.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the comment is right, you are mixing python code and bash commands calls.  But Jupyter and IPython are misleading new users because of some facilities it proposes.
If you really want to call bash commands from inside your python notebook, prefix your line with a ! (exclamation mark)

For instance:
!chmod +x hello.py

Comment: 'chmod' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: This is the error I get when I put the exclamation mark

Comment: On what system is running your Jupyter server ? I suspect that it is running on Windows. In that case, chmod (which is a pure Unix command) could not be available